# Auto-loading Helpers in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, autoload, helper

I've been trying to get Laravel 4 to auto-load helper files from the `app/helpers` directory (I created this, obviously).

I started by doing it the Composer way: add the path to `composer.json`, and then running `dump-autoload`. This did not work. I then tried with the `app/start/global.php` file, which did not work either.

Note, I am not throwing classes into the helper files - that's what Facades and Packages are for. I only need small helper functions, similar to those of Laravel's own (in the `vendor` directory). I only say this because it seems that composers dump lists classes (with namespaces) only.

What can I do to get the helpers to auto-load?

#### Update

It also seems that the `ClassLoader::addDirectories()` function does not work for classes - why is it there then? Do I have to use both this and Composer?

### Edit

It seems my question is not being understood. In my `app/helpers` directory, I have a file called `paths.php`. I want to be able to call a function within it (`theme_path($location)`) within the global scope.

Comment: Do you have any code, so we can get a better idea of what's in the file that you want to load?

Comment: Just a simple function: `theme_path($location)`, which returns `Config::get('site.theme') . "/$location"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoloading is only for classes, you can't really autoload random php files based on one of their function names.

Your best bet is go OOP and use classes for your helpers. You'll gain the efficiency of autoloaded files only when needed, and you'll be closer to what the rest of the Laravel community does.

But if you still want to use plain old non-object php functions, I guess you could simply individually `require()` all of them from start.php, but they'd all be loaded on every page request.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to take the OOP approach. I do know that it's better, but some end users get quite confused - I'm really just trying to make things a little easier for them. So, in combination with your suggestion, I'm extending the templating engine to make things a bit more hunky-dory for my end users.

Answer (score 9):

You need to do the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "file location go here"
    ]
},
```

Then you'll be able to use the functions in the helper file. However it's worth noting that this will load the file explicitly on every request. See http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files for more details.

I would recommend that unless this is a heavily used file of helpers, avoid doing this and just organise it with namespaces and classes to avoid naming collisions.

Comment: Darn, so I can't get it to work with directories? I guess this seems plausible - besides, there won't be that many helper files...

Comment: You could alternatively iterate over a directory of files and use require, as each files in the files composer autoload schema equates to a require statement in the composer generated autoload_real.php.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I can show you my composer and helpers to show how I made it to work:

```
"autoload": {

    "psr-0": {
        "Helpers": "app/libraries"
    }
}
```

And then in app/libraries/Helpers/DateHelper.php (for instance)

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class DateHelper extends \DateTime {


}
```

After creating the helper file I just run the

> composer dump-autoload

And now just use your helper as Helpers\DateHelper

Comment: Like I said, I'm not using classes here. Just functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question, but Laravel has integrated Carbon library (https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) for dates handling. It's inside `vendor/nesbot` folder, so you can use it directly in Laravel.